# Accessibility implications of showing/hiding vs. adding/removing from DOM

Tags: javascript, dom, accessibility

Below is an example of a drop-down menu, written in Angular, in which I use the HTML5 `hidden` attribute (in other words, `display: none;`) to show/hide a list of items:

```
<button
  id="my-btn
  type="button"
  aria-haspopup="menu"
  aria-controls="my-menu"
  [attr.aria-expanded]="isMenuOpen"
  (click)="isMenuOpen = !isMenuOpen"
>
  Menu
</button>

<ul
  id="my-menu"
  role="menu"
  aria-labelledby="my-btn"
  [hidden]="!isMenuOpen"
>
  ...
</ul>
```

In this next example, I use the structural directive `*ngIf` instead of attribute `hidden` to conditionally render the list. In other word, the list is now added and removed from the DOM every time `isMenuOpen` changes.

```
<ul
  id="my-menu"
  role="menu"
  aria-labelledby="my-btn"
  *ngIf="isMenuOpen"
>
  ...
</ul>
```

Ignoring any framework or performance concerns, **are these two implementations any different from an accessibility standpoint**?

Quite a few ARIA attributes work by referencing other elements' IDs (e.g. `aria-controls`, `aria-labelledby`, etc.) Is removing from the DOM an element referenced by such an attribute any less accessible than hiding that element?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, there is a difference.  Consider this simple example:

```
<button aria-labelledby="foo"></button>
```

where the "foo" element does not exist on the page (yet).  If you ran this code through a validator such as https://validator.w3.org/nu, it would fail.

`Error: The aria-labelledby attribute must point to an element in the same document.`

From a WCAG perspective, it would fail [4.1.1 - Parsing](https://www.w3.org/TR/UNDERSTANDING-WCAG20/ensure-compat-parses.html).

Also, WCAG [4.1.2 - Name, Role, Value](https://www.w3.org/TR/UNDERSTANDING-WCAG20/ensure-compat-rsv.html) would be an issue.  The button (in my example) does not have an accessible name because the element it points to does not exist.  If the element it points to is hidden (instead of non-existent), then the accessible name **could** be calculated, as noted in step 2A of the [Accessible Name and Description Computation](https://www.w3.org/TR/accname-1.1/#step2).

Screen reader users have shortcut keys they can use that make navigation fast and easy.  If I want to navigate to the next button on the page, I can simply press 'B' (while the screen reader is running) and my focus will move to the next button.  The name of the button will be announced but if the element it points to doesn't exist, there will be no name to announce.

I can also bring up a dialog with a list of all the buttons on the page (if I'm using the JAWS screen reader) by pressing <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>ins</kbd>+<kbd>b</kbd>.  The list will display the accessible name of all the buttons.  Again, if your button points to an element that doesn't exist, there will not be a name to display in that dialog.

With VoiceOver on iOS, I can set my rotor to navigate by buttons so that when I swipe up or down, the focus moves to the next button (similar to pressing 'B' with a PC screen reader).  When the focus moves to the next button, it's name will be calculated and announced.  So again, if the element it points to does not exist, a name will not be announced.

So the simple answer to your question is to use hidden elements instead of elements that are created/destroyed in the DOM, but I wanted to give some context behind that answer.